# How do I get rid of unwanted ANSI escape characters printed when using gawk / awk and jq?

Tags: awk, gawk, jq

I am using jq to parse json files to text and vice versa in bash script.

I have faced this problem while trying to parse a text file line by line, to make it a json object.

Here is my input file :

```
default
———————————
out           0-65535  0.0.0.0/0          -1  
in            80       0.0.0.0/0          tcp 
in            8080     0.0.0.0/0          tcp 
in            21017    192.168.1.0/32     tcp 
in            2379     0.0.0.0/0          udp 
in            0-65535  sg-10fa3c75        -1  
===========
dev-external
———————————
out           0-65535  4.1.0.0/32         -1  
in            1-2      sg-10fa3c75        -1  
in            21034    sg-10fa3c75        tcp 
in            9418     24.115.129.102/32  tcp 
in            80       0.0.0.0/0          tcp 
in            8080     default            tcp 
in            21017    192.168.1.0/0      tcp 
in            123-655  1.45.9.1/32        -1  
===========
my-sg
———————————
out           0-65535  0.0.0.0/0          -1  
in            80       0.0.0.0/0          tcp 
in            8070     0.0.0.0/0          tcp 
in            8080     0.0.0.0/0          tcp 
in            21017    192.168.1.0/32     tcp 
in            0-65535  sg-10fa3c75        -1  
===========
```

I tried to parse this file using gawk:

`gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\n=+\n"; FS="\n"; ORS="\n"} { print $1 }'`

which returns :

```
default                                                                                                                                                                             
dev-external
my-sg
```

but when I parse this using jq :

`| jq -R . | jq -s .`

I have these unwanted escape characters attached.

```
[
  "\u001b[3g\r\u001bH            \u001bH            \u001bH              \u001bH            \u001bH            \u001bH            \u001bH            \u001bH            \u001bH            \u001bH            \u001bH            \u001bH            \u001bH            \u001bH            \u001bH            \u001bH\rdefault",
  "dev-external",
  "my-sg"
]
```

Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusing thing for me was the non-ascii `—` character, but I was able to make it work in `awk` & `sed` by copy/pasting the char into the following:

```
awk '/^—/ {d=1} /^=/ {d=0; next} !d'
sed '/^—/,/^=/ d'
```

Here are the results:

```
$ awk '/^—/ {d=1} /^=/ {d=0; next} !d' esc.txt | jq -R . | jq -s
[
  "default",
  "dev-external",
  "my-sg"
]
$ sed '/^—/,/^=/ d' esc.txt | jq -R . | jq -s
[
  "default",
  "dev-external",
  "my-sg"
]
```

If we want to make it more obvious that we are trying to match a non-ascii character, we can leverage the feature in `awk` to match on the octal representation of the character:

```
$ awk '/^\342\200\224/ {d=1} /^=/ {d=0; next} !d' esc.txt | jq -R . | jq -s
[
  "default",
  "dev-external",
  "my-sg"
]
```

*(Numbers found using* `od` *and "trial and error.")*

Answer (score 1):

From the [`jq` manual page](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), one of these options seems likely to help:

> - --color-output / -C and --monochrome-output / -M:
>
> By default, jq outputs colored JSON if writing to a terminal. You can
> force it to produce color even if writing to a pipe or a file using
> -C, and disable color with -M.
>
> - --ascii-output / -a:
>
> jq usually outputs non-ASCII Unicode codepoints as UTF-8, even if the
> input specified them as escape sequences (like “\u03bc”). Using this
> option, you can force jq to produce pure ASCII output with every
> non-ASCII character replaced with the equivalent escape sequence.

(posted as an answer even though it's more-comment like because it's too long and would be unreadable as a comment - and it might even be right...)